# sysctl prameters seem not working on a VM

Tags: tcp, sysctl, tuning

I am trying to tune my servers performance. To do so, I wanted to test some sysctl prameters such as `net.core.somaxconn`, `net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog` and `net.core.netdev_max_backlog`.

Following were my setup:

- A `4vCPU` server running nginx docker container as a test web server which serves a static page.
- one `16vCPU`, one `8vCPU` and one `4vCPU` as my load generators on nginx server using `locust` framework.

With default sysctl parameters on webserver VM, I could get about a `15k` RPS. After changing `net.core.somaxconn`, `net.ipv4.tcp_max_syn_backlog` and `net.core.netdev_max_backlog` to either higher values or lower values the results didn't change. I even set them to `1` and still `15k` RPS. Then I ran `netstat -s  | grep LISTEN` to see if some packets dropped because of full `syn` of `accept` queues, and I expected something like `123456 SYNs to LISTEN sockets dropped` from the output. But it didn't output anything.

I tested some other sysctl prameters. For instance I set `net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_time`, `net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_probes` and `net.ipv4.tcp_keepalive_intvl` all to 0. But still after running `netstat -a | grep -i wait`, I could see a lot of connections are in `TIME_WAIT` state. Is there something wrong? Can you please help me with that?